# What is the equivalent of @WebParam in .NET WebMethods?

Tags: .net, web-services, asmx, webmethod

I have a Java JWS WebService defined like this:

```
@WebService
public class Foo
{
    @WebMethod
    public int foo(@WebParam(name = "externalName") String internalName)
    {
        ...
    }
}
```

The equivalent of this in C# .NET seems to be

```
[WebService]
public class Foo : System.Web.Services.WebService
{
    [WebMethod]
    public int foo(/* ??? */ string internalName)
    {
        ...
    }
}
```

What should go in the place of the `/* ??? */`? I can't find the documentation on this.

Comment: ASMX is a legacy technology, and should not be used for new development. WCF should be used for all new development of web service clients and servers. One hint: Microsoft has retired the [ASMX Forum](http://social.msdn.microsoft.com/Forums/en-US/asmxandxml/threads) on MSDN.

Comment: do you really need a diferent name for the parameter? if you use the same internal and external name your code work..

Comment: @John Saunders, yes, and it's a legacy project I'm working on.

Comment: @Luis Tellez, yes, I need to define a parameter with a name that's a keyword in C#.

Answer (score 2):

I believe you may be looking for `[XmlElement]`:

```
[WebMethod]
public int foo([XmlElement("externalName")] string internalName)
{
    ...
}
```

Answer (score 1):

> yes, I need to define a parameter with a name that's a keyword in C#

The `@` symbol would allow you to use reserved words of c#

```
[WebMethod]
public int foo(int @int)
{
    @int += 2;
    ...
}
```